# How to render a foreign key field in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Desired outcome: When I render a Poller and its associated comments
I would like to also render the `Vote` a user selected for the Poller along with his comment (Note: A user can only comment if he voted on that poller).

Side note: A user can make one vote to a Poller and post one comment to a Poller. He can only comment if he voted beforehand.

```
# Models

class Poller(models.Model):
    poller_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    poller_text = models.CharField(max_length=333)
    poller_choice_one = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    poller_choice_two = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Vote(models.Model):
    poller = models.ForeignKey(Poller, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vote')
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    poller_choice_one_vote = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    poller_choice_two_vote = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Vote by {self.user}'


class Comment(models.Model):
    poller = models.ForeignKey(Poller, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='PollerComment')
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=350)
    flag_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    upvote_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downvote_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

```
# View

@require_GET
def render_single_poller(request, poller_id):

    # Retrieve comments associated to the Poller
    comments_qs = PollerComment.objects.filter(poller_id=poller_id)

context = {
        'comments_qs': comments_qs,
    }
    return render(request, 'pollboard/single_poller.html', context)
```

I tried to do it via a template filter like so:

```
# pollboard_tags.py

@register.filter(name='get_vote')
def get_voted(self):
    self.vote_made = 'Test'
    print(self.vote.poller_choice_one_vote)
    if self.vote.poller_choice_one_vote:
        self.vote_made = 'One'
    else:
        self.vote_made = 'Two'
    return self.vote_made
```

```
# template

<div class="commentors-poller-choice">{{ comment|get_vote }}</div>
```

throws

> RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /poller/68c725eb-277e-4b5b-a61b-b4a02bf5e854/
> PollerComment has no vote.

I fear that I'm already overcomplicating things here. I hope there is a more straightforward solution to this like idk expanding the comments queryset by the required information for rendering?

Comment: Try to change `self.vote = 'Two'` to `self.vote_made = 'Two'`. If `self.vote.poller_choice_one_vote` returns false, `self.vote_made` will be blank

Comment: @BrianD ah thanks for the hint, but it still doesnt return anything.. I do render other fields in the template loop though, so the queryset is existent

Comment: How are you filtering with `PollerComment`? `PollerComment` is a related name and not a model right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user can vote on a poller only once, you can filter with:

```
@register.filter(name='get_vote')
def get_voted(self):
    vote = Vote.objects.get(poller=self.poller, user=self.user)
    return 'One' if vote.poller_choice_one_vote else 'Two'
```